# No pdf output for some of the included chapters in final compilation file (No error message)

Tags: include

I have created each chapter file (`.tex`) which starts with `\chapter{chapter name}` and then I am trying to include all the files in one final document to create one `.pdf` file. In pdf output I see all other chapters included except one. It doesn't even recognize it as a chapter. It is neither in `\tableofcontents` nor in main body. Here's my minimal code. Can someone help me? I also referred other similar questions but none of them helped.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[total={6in, 8in}, margin=1in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{apalike}

\begin{document}
\include{Abstract}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\include{Chapter 1}
\include{Chapter 2}
.
.
.
\include{Summary}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the space between `Chapter` and `1` etc.? Spaces in filenames is never a good idea!

Comment: Ahhh yes, this is the only file having space in between. Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: Wow. That worked. Thank you very much Christian. You saved my day. Can I ask one simple question here? Regarding including bibliography in \tableofcontents in my case?

Comment: Well, you can give `\usepackage[nottoc,notlof]{tocbibind}` a try. If you prefer to have the ToC and the LoF in your ToC as well, remove the `nottoc` and `notlof` options, however. But ... this is another question :-P

Comment: Thank you again Christian. This worked perfectly fine. Can't thank you enough for the help. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue(s) could be solved in comments

Comment: Yes, sure. Perfectly solved. Dankeschön.